# JavaFX MediaPlayer change media

Tags: java, javafx

Currently I am on an assignment where we have to create a mediaplayer.
I am using the JavaFX MediaPlayer, but it does not have a way of changing the media, without creating the object as a new MediaPlayer everytime you want change media.
I have been looking around for a library of some sort, which have this support, but I have not yet been able to find one.
My question is if this is even a possibility, if such a thing exist, or if the correct way would be to just create the new MediaPlayer every time I want to switch media?

Comment: Short answer:  Yes, you need to create a new MediaPlayer for each new Media.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#MediaPlayer-javafx.scene.media.Media-): *"`public MediaPlayer​(Media media)` Create a player for a specific media. This is the only way to associate a Media object with a MediaPlayer: once the player is created it cannot be changed."*.